# C# InvaildOperationException Collection was modified

Tags: c#

I am having an issue with my C# application, it runs fine or x amount of minutes but hits an error at some point which complains about 'InvaildOperationException Collection was modified'. I am quite new to C# and i am unable to find the solution even after reading other posts.

From what i can tell after reading the posts it is something to do with my for loop, could anyone be so kind as to tell me what i have done wrong.

The error i think is caused by the UpdateGraph function.

The code is designed to connect to a Cisco router and get the cellular data via Serial and show it in a graph and richTextBox which is all working minus the error i get at some point :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Cisco_Cellular_Diagnostics
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort serialPort;
        string[] ports;
        string rawStrings;
        int ComPort_ComboBoxIndex;
        bool serialIsOpen = false;
        bool autoScroll = false;
        readonly String executingFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        TextWriter txtFile;
        List<int> bandwidthArray = new List<int>();
        List<int> rssiArray = new List<int>();
        List<int> rsrpArray = new List<int>();
        List<int> rsrqArray = new List<int>();
        List<int> snrArray = new List<int>();
        List<int> nearbyCellsArray = new List<int>();

        private static System.Timers.Timer pollingTimer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip
            {
                AutoPopDelay = 5000,
                InitialDelay = 500,
                ReshowDelay = 500,
                ShowAlways = true
            };
            ComPortComboBox.Items.AddRange(ports);
            ComPortComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

            autoScroll = true;

            pollingTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            pollingTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SendCellularCmd);

            Console.WriteLine("executingFolder = " + executingFolder);
            String fileDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("d").Replace("/", "-");
            txtFile = new StreamWriter(executingFolder + "\\Cisco Celluar log " + fileDate + ".txt", true);

            LoadChart();
        }

        private void LoadChart()
        {
            var chart = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
            chart.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
            chart.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "";
            chart.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
            chart.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
            chart.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chart.AxisY.Minimum = -128;
            chart.AxisY.Maximum = 128;
            chart.AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart.AxisY.Interval = 16;
            chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
            chart.AxisX.Title = "Reading";
            chart.AxisY.Title = "dB";
            //chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;

            chart1.Series.Add("Bandwidth");
            chart1.Series["Bandwidth"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["Bandwidth"].Color = Color.Green;
            chart1.Series["Bandwidth"].BorderWidth = 8;

            chart1.Series.Add("RSSI");
            chart1.Series["RSSI"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["RSSI"].Color = Color.Blue;
            chart1.Series["RSSI"].BorderWidth = 8;

            chart1.Series.Add("RSRP");
            chart1.Series["RSRP"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["RSRP"].Color = Color.Yellow;
            chart1.Series["RSRP"].BorderWidth = 8;

            chart1.Series.Add("RSRQ");
            chart1.Series["RSRQ"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["RSRQ"].Color = Color.Red;
            chart1.Series["RSRQ"].BorderWidth = 8;

            chart1.Series.Add("SNR");
            chart1.Series["SNR"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["SNR"].Color = Color.Purple;
            chart1.Series["SNR"].BorderWidth = 8;

            chart1.Series.Add("Nearby cells");
            chart1.Series["Nearby cells"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["Nearby cells"].Color = Color.DarkGray;
            chart1.Series["Nearby cells"].BorderWidth = 8;

            chart1.Series["Bandwidth"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["RSSI"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["RSRP"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["RSRQ"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["SNR"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["Nearby cells"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
        }

        private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

            BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                rawStrings += indata;
                //txtFile.Write(indata);
                //txtFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "\n");
                ReceivedDataRichTextBox.AppendText(indata);
                if (autoScroll)
                    ReceivedDataRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
            });
        }

        private void OpenSerial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComPort_ComboBoxIndex = ComPortComboBox.SelectedIndex;
            if (ComPort_ComboBoxIndex >= 0 && !serialIsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    string selectedCOM = ComPortComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    serialPort = new SerialPort(selectedCOM, 9600);

                    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 3000;
                    serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                    serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                    serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                
                    serialIsOpen = true;
                    serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort_DataReceived);
                    OpenSerialOne.Text = "Close Serial";

                    serialPort.Open();
                    LogIntoCLI();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            else if (serialIsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    serialPort.Write("exit");
                    serialPort.Close();
                    txtFile.Close();
                    pollingTimer.Enabled = false;
                    serialIsOpen = false;
                    OpenSerialOne.Text = "Open Serial";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, check the baud Rate and COM port is selected and try again.");
            }
        }

        private void LogIntoCLI()
        {
            if (serialIsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    serialPort.Write("\r");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    serialPort.Write("\r"); // "exit\r"
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    serialPort.Write("enable\r");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    serialPort.Write("met0cean\r");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    pollingTimer.Enabled = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void SendCellularCmd(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExtractData();
            serialPort.Write("show cell 0 radio\r");
            Console.WriteLine("sending command...");
        }

        private void ExtractData()
        {
            try
            {
                txtFile.Write(rawStrings);
                txtFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "\n");

                String[] listOfStrings = rawStrings.Split('\n');

                rawStrings = "";

                foreach (String value in listOfStrings)
                {
                    String[] strlist = value.Split(' ');
                
                    if (value.IndexOf("Bandwidth") >= 0 && strlist.Length == 5)
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(strlist[3], out int extractedValue))
                            UpdateGraph(extractedValue, "Bandwidth", ref bandwidthArray);
                    }
                    else if (value.IndexOf("RSSI") >= 0 && strlist.Length == 5)
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(strlist[3], out int extractedValue))
                            UpdateGraph(extractedValue, "RSSI", ref rssiArray);
                    }
                    else if (value.IndexOf("RSRP") >= 0 && strlist.Length == 5)
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(strlist[3], out int extractedValue))
                            UpdateGraph(extractedValue, "RSRP", ref rsrpArray);
                    }
                    else if (value.IndexOf("RSRQ") >= 0 && strlist.Length == 5)
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(strlist[3], out int extractedValue))
                            UpdateGraph(extractedValue, "RSRQ", ref rsrqArray);
                    }
                    else if (value.IndexOf("SNR") >= 0 && strlist.Length == 5)
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(strlist[3], out int extractedValue))
                            UpdateGraph(extractedValue, "SNR", ref snrArray);
                    }
                    else if (value.IndexOf("nearby cells") >= 0 && strlist.Length == 6)
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(strlist[5], out int extractedValue))
                            UpdateGraph(extractedValue, "Nearby cells", ref nearbyCellsArray);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateGraph(int a_value, String a_ID, ref List<int> a_List) 
        {
            try
            {
                // keep the list count to 20 items 
                if (a_List.Count == 20)
                    a_List.RemoveAt(0);
                a_List.Add(a_value);

                // clear chart and add items
                chart1.Series[a_ID].Points.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < a_List.Count; i++)
                {
                    chart1.Series[a_ID].Points.AddXY(i, a_List[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnFormClosing(e);

            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

            // Confirm user wants to close
            switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to close?", "Closing Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
            {
                case DialogResult.No:
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    try
                    {
                        txtFile.Close();
                        serialPort.Write("exit");
                        serialPort.Close();
                        pollingTimer.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void PollingTimeNumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pollingTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(PollingTimeNumericUpDown.Value);
        }

        private void ClearDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReceivedDataRichTextBox.Clear();
            chart1.Series["Bandwidth"].Points.Clear();
            chart1.Series["RSSI"].Points.Clear();
            chart1.Series["RSRP"].Points.Clear();
            chart1.Series["RSRQ"].Points.Clear();
            chart1.Series["SNR"].Points.Clear();
            chart1.Series["Nearby cells"].Points.Clear();

            chart1.Series["Bandwidth"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["RSSI"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["RSRP"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["RSRQ"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["SNR"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            chart1.Series["Nearby cells"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
        }

        private void SendManualCmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                
                serialPort.Write(textBox1.Text + "\r");
                textBox1.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void ReloadComPortsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComPortComboBox.Items.Clear();
            ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            ComPortComboBox.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }

        private void ComComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // CiscoComPort = ComPortComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is giving exception?

Comment: You are using `System.Timers.Timer`, and then kicking off an event handler that updates the UI. This is not safe. You will have to `Invoke` all code that updates the UI so that the UI updating is handled by the main thread.

Comment: May i be so dumb as to ask how please, i have been struggling for a while.

Comment: Try changing to a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1) instead.